# Checkbox doesn't respond to onChange when checked is driven by state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I have a material-ui `Table` and have been implementing multi-select functionality on it.

My multi select should behave as follows :

- Select checkboxes only appear at the start of a row on hover (when nothing has been selected)
- Once one row has been selected, all other checkboxes become permanently visible.
- The checkbox in the `TableHead` will select / deselect all rows in the `Table` when toggled.

Each row has its own individual unique `id`.

I maintain a `Set` called `idsOfSelectedRows` via a `useState` hook to keep track of all rows currently selected.

Each `TableRow` has a `Checkbox` which looks like this

```
<Checkbox
  className={
     idsOfSelectedRows.size === 0 &&
     styles.rowSelectionCheckboxStyle
  }
  onChange={() => handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick}
  checked={idsOfSelectedRows.has(row.id)}
 />
```

and `handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick` looks like this

```
  const handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick = event => {
    const idOfClickedRow = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;
   //If the checkbox has just become checked then add it to the idOfSelectedRows Set, otherwise remove it.
    setIdsOfSelectedRows(
      event.target.checked
        ? new Set(idsOfSelectedRows.add(String(idOfClickedRow)))
        : () => {
            idsOfSelectedRows.delete(String(idOfClickedRow));
            return new Set(idsOfSelectedRows);
          }
    );
  };
```

My issue is that clicking on the checkboxes on the rows is unresponsive. I can select them all by clicking on the **select all** `Checkbox` in the `TableHead` but **clicking on checkboxes in individual rows does not change their state ?**

Here's a full CodeSandbox reproducing the exact issue. *What do I need to do to make the checkboxes in the rows be toggleable ?*

[image: Edit hover-table-row-checkbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;`
won't give you the required id, since there isn't one passed, change the `chekbox` like so:

```
<Checkbox
    id={row.id}
    onChange={handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick}
    checked={idsOfSelectedRows.has(row.id)}
/>
```

Then, retreive the ID like so:

```
const idOfClickedRow = event.target.attributes.id.value;
```

[Updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-table-row-checkbox-fbdf4?file=/src/MyTableComponent.js):

[image: Edit hover-table-row-checkbox]

---

Like the other answers suggest, change the `handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick` function call like shown in the example.
If you like your solution with an anonymous function, you should add the `()`: `onChange={() => handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick()}`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `() =>` from the `onChange` assignment for a quick fix.

**Why**

You're declaring an anonymous inline function, but that function does not call anything (missing `()` that is syntax to call a function). `onChange` accepts a function reference. When you give it an inline function, that's the function it will call. The other option is to only pass it the function *reference* of `handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick`, and then that function will be called on change instead of the anonymous function middleman.

So your two options are:

```js
onChange={handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick} // Just the reference
```

OR

```js
onChange={(e) => handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick(e)} // New inline function that calls your function
```

The second way is unnecessary in most cases. The first is preferred unless you need to pass custom parameters. Here is an example of how it might be useful:

```js
onChange={(e) => handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick(e, id)}
```

In your sandbox, you map over elements and each gets a change handler. To treat them separately in the handler, you can pass an extra variable to the function like above.

For example, I got your sandbox working by changing the handler and assignment to this:

```js
const handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick = (event, idOfClickedRow) => {

...

onChange={(e) => handleRowSelectionCheckboxClick(e, row.id)}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work in my CodeSandbox example unfortunately.

Comment: Your sandbox looks like it has some other issues with it as well. Not related to this specific problem. I updated my answer with an extra relevant example.